# Sublime/Mavensmate: tests run but can't find leads or documents in database

Tags: apex, sandbox, mavensmate, sublime

The first line of one of my Apex class tests reads like so:

```
@isTest
    public class ImportOrganizerTest {
    static testMethod void validateImportOrganizer() {
        Integer oldLeadCount = Database.countQuery('select count() from lead');
```

This returns zero, but there are two leads in my project's sandbox (which is what MM is connecting to). Are there any settings for me to check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, test classes cannot see the data in your environment. You need to create this data before / at the beginning of your test methods.

There are some great articles & even a Trailhead module:

[Set Up Test Data for an Entire Test Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses)

[Creating Test Data for Apex Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_testing/apex_testing_data)

In short, you should create general test records in a @testSetup method. This creates a sample dataset which is present for each test method.

Then alter the dataset in each test method as needed before running your actual test logic.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, yeah. Thanks! That'd go for documents I need to upload too, yeah?

Comment: Yep you'll need to create test documents too.